# Reading Matlab data in python with scipy.io

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, scipy

I am trying to read some experimental conditions from a MATLAB 5.0 file using scipy.io. The problem is the output file is a ridiculously complicated series of arrays. How can I filter through the data within the matlab file?

```
import scipy.io as sio
with open("sequence_output.txt", "w") as f:
    mat = sio.loadmat("seq_data.seq")
    f.write(str(mat))
```

This gives me something like the below in the output file. (The actual file is > 800 lines).

How can I pick out the data I need from this file?

```
{'__header__': b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: PCWIN, Created on: Thu Mar 15 13:50:48 2018', '__version__': '1.0', '__globals__': [], 'StepData': array([[(array([[1]], dtype=uint8), array(['LoadPlate'], dtype='<U9'), array([[1]], dtype=uint8), array([[1]], dtype=uint8), array([[0]], dtype=uint8), array([[0]], dtype=uint8), array([[(array([[12]], dtype=uint8), array([[8]], dtype=uint8), array([[0]], dtype=uint8), array([[1]], dtype=uint8), array([[60]], dtype=uint8), array([[1]], dtype=uint8), array([[1]], dtype=uint8), array([[(array([[1]], dtype=uint8), array([[0]], dtype=uint8)),
        (array([[1]], dtype=uint8), array([[0]], dtype=uint8)),
        (array([[1]], dtype=uint8), array([[0]], dtype=uint8)),
        (array([[1]], dtype=uint8), array([[0]], dtype=uint8)),
        (array([[1]], dtype=uint8), array([[0]], dtype=uint8)),
        (array([[1]], dtype=uint8), array([[0]], dtype=uint8)),
        (array([[1]], dtype=uint8), array([[0]], dtype=uint8)),
        (array([[1]], dtype=uint8), array([[0]], dtype=uint8)),
        (array([[0]], dtype=uint8), array([[0]], dtype=uint8)),
        (array([[0]], dtype=uint8), array([[0]], dtype=uint8)),
        (array([[0]], dtype=uint8), array([[0]], dtype=uint8)),
        (array([[0]], dtype=uint8), array([[0]], dtype=uint8)),
        (array([[0]], dtype=uint8), array([[0]], dtype=uint8)),
        (array([[0]], dtype=uint8), array([[0]], dtype=uint8)),
```

Comment: The potentially useful data exists in the following format:
`dtype=[('Selected', 'O'), ('Value', 'O')]), array(['13-Mar-2018'], dtype='<U11'), array(['MG2'], dtype='<U3'), array(['15-Mar-2018'], dtype='<U11'), array([[(array(['M2=Kcv-09-03b'], dtype='<U13'), array([], dtype='<U1'), array([[1]], dtype=uint8), array([[8]], dtype=uint8)),
        (array(['M2=Kcv-09-03&Kir3.4T'], dtype='<U20'), array([], dtype='<U1'), array([[25]], dtype=uint8), array([[38]], dtype=uint8)),`

Answer (score 0):

`mat['StepData']` appears to a be a 2d array, containing one string dtype array, and whole bunch of `uint8` arrays (all being (1,1) arrays).  `shape` of this array may be (1,n) but the display is incomplete.  `dtype` is `object` since it contain arrays as elements.  The MATLAB source was probably a `cell`.

I can't copy-n-paste your comment to further decipher it, but it too looks like a mix of string arrays and `uint8` ones.

MATLAB matrices are loaded as numpy numeric or string arrays.  They will always be 2d (or higher), and may be transposed (or order='F').

MATLAB cells can have a mix of contents (numeric, string, etc) and are loaded as object dtype arrays.

MATLAB struct are loaded as structured arrays, with field names corresponding to the struct fields/attributes.

Search on '[scipy] loadmat' to see other questions about using `loadmat`